# To what extent do code-signing certificates boost sales of your software?

Tags: installation, certificate, code-signing, uac

In the experiences of all the programmers on Stackoverflow, have you found a certificate to boost sales of your (downloadable) program?

I produce .NET software and upon clicking the installation file, Windows 7 pops up a message saying the software is from an "unknown publisher" and to proceed with caution. For Windows 8, this appears to be even more prominent, and may adversely affect the number of downloads, and therefore the number of sales. A certificate will help soften this 'warning' by (for example) changing the warning's colour from orange to blue, and give the publisher's name instead of 'unknown'.

But I'd like more tangible evidence since many people are obviously used to that message, and may not care and download anyway. So has anyone noticed a jump in sales after the switch?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about certificates and installation and not about the code itself.

Comment: It is something though that affects all programmers who try to make a living out of software, myself included, and can hopefully be of use to many people as a result. I can't think of any better place to ask than here.

Comment: I agree it's a valid question, I'm just not sure it's on-topic for SO (although I may be wrong). Perhaps someone might be able to suggest a more appropriate place to ask if it would be better elsewhere - I'm not sure where would be best.